# "NO MATCH" returned after a few prints in KEPServerEX and stops printing

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I'm new to this KEP and OPC thingy so please bear with me. We are upgrading our old labeling system that's still using obsolete technologies (Windows XP, .Net 2.0, KEPDirect, etc). We are now using KEPServerEX (purchased license already), upgraded our client app and other related apps, and everything else. After some successful local tests using Simulator Driver, we did deploy them to one of our new machines for UAT. We get successful continuous label prints but after some time we suddenly get a "NO MATCH" and the machines stops printing. On average, we get about 20 continuous prints. We only got 3 to 5 times that we got 100+ continuous prints before getting a "NO MATCH". I think the "NO MATCH" is displayed in the PLC. I'm not at the fulfillment center where the machines are so I don't see. After some playing around with the code, we concluded that the issue is not there but might be in the settings in the KEPServerEX or somwhere else. We also already had one setting changed to KEPServerEX that was in the old KEPDirect and that is for the "Optimization Method" value which we changed from "Write All Values for All Tags" to "Write Only Latest Value for All Tags" because when we used "Write All Values for All Tags", we get the same labels printed multiple times (more than 5) but using "Write Only Latest Value for All Tags" didn't print duplicate labels. Any idea what we might be missing?
Also, I removed the tags in KEPServerEX that we don't actually need in the app but is being sent in to KEPServerEX.

Here are also some more details of our setup:

The KepServerEX and client app (windows service) are both running on the same machine

```
ColdSeals are: two 9000 series and one 900 series from System Packaging
2 labelers: weber 5300 with zebra500 print engine
1 labeler: weber5200 with zebra 170pax4 print engine
Scanners have six total. Three of them are Datalogic DS4800. Three are Accu Sort 22 series 2.

KepServerEX Settings
Type Channel/Driver: AutomationDirect ECOM
Duty Cycle: 10
Device Model: DL-260
Scan Mode: Respect Tag-Specified Scan Rate
Initial Updates from Cache: Disable
Connect Timeout: 2s
Request Timeout (ms) : 400
Attempts Before Timeout : 5
Demote on Failure: Disable
Optimization Method: "Write Only Latest Value for All Tags"
```

expecting continuous printing of labels but stops after getting a "NO MATCH" error